# How can I get the next key, from a specific key in a map?

Tags: java, dictionary, key

I have something like:

`Map<Integer, String> topology = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();`

Which contains for example:

```
01, my.vm.01.serv.com
04, my.vm.04.serv.com
07, my.vm.07.serv.com
08, my.vm.08.serv.com
09, my.vm.09.serv.com
```

I'd like to be able to say "I have key `07`, get me the next key in the map from this point", which would ideally return `08`.

Is there a way to do this without using an iterator?

Answer (score 4):

> "I have key 07, get me the next key in the map from this point",

If you do not want to change the definition of `Map`, you could try something like

```
List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(topology.keySet());
Integer integer = keys.get((keys.indexOf(7))+1); // next key
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `topology.ceilingKey(7)` to get the next key.

Note that this is a method of the `NavigableMap` interface, so you'll have to store your `TreeMap` instance in a `NavigableMap` variable.

```
NavigableMap<Integer, String> topology = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
```

Comment: While *topology* = *a Map*?